# Studying relativity from Landau

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I'd like to have an advice from you. I was thinking about studying for the exam of general relativity from Landau II: theory of fields. I already studied mechanics and fluid dynamics from Landau and I loved those books in every aspect. I couldn't find a better book in these two topics so I have to give credit to Landau about general relativity too.

The problem here is that our professor strongly suggested other textbooks saying that we could study from Landau but it would be way too hard with respect to books like:

Bernard F. Schutz, A first course in general relativity

S. Weinberg, Gravitation and Cosmology

And once we learn relativity from those we may approach the study of Landau, but only after having already studied it. And at that point it would be almost pointless to restudy it from nothing since you already know the topic.

I'd like an advice from people who knows at least one of these books. How they are? Is Landau really too hard or it's just the usual representation people make about his books, confusing the concept of being too difficult with the concept of "it forces you to think"? As I said I love the 2 books of Landau I studied from so I'd like to have very good reason not to study relativity form his text.

Ah, notation is not a problem.

Edit: It isn't a duplicate. I explicitly asked about Landau's book which is quoted twice in that post. And only one answer says something about it. Plus there's no confront of Landau with other books. The main point here is Landau's book which is not there

Comment: Sorry but I don't think it is a duplicate. I explicitly asked about Landau's book which is quoted twice in that post. And only one answer says something about it. Plus there's no confront of Landau with other books. The main point here is Landau's book which is not there.

Comment: Landau has some nice perspectives you often won't find in other places, but I find that book horribly outdated in the context of GR, both in terms of mathematics and in terms of recent developments in physics. For an introductory book I recommend Spacetime and Geometry by Sean Carroll. It doesn't butcher mathematics, it is didactic/pedagogical, and it is modern.

Comment: @Uldreth Thank you, I'll keep that in mind and look for the book you told me!